# Add percentage increase to all WooCommerce shipping rates programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to add a 65% increase across all shipping methods.

I've used variations of this function but this doesn't affect the rates that are returned.

```
function increase_shipping_costs() {
  // Get the current shipping rates
  $shipping_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

  foreach ( $shipping_zones as $zone ) {
    foreach ( $zone['shipping_methods'] as $shipping_method ) {
      // Check if the shipping method is a flat rate
      if ( !$shipping_method->id === 'free_shipping' ) {
        // Get the current cost
        $current_cost = $shipping_method->cost;

        // Calculate the increased cost
        $increased_cost = $current_cost + ( $current_cost * 0.65 );

        // Update the shipping cost
        $shipping_method->cost = $increased_cost;
        $shipping_method->save();
      }
    }
  }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'increase_shipping_costs', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a 65% increase cost across all shipping methods rates, `woocommerce_package_rates` is the correct filter hook to be used, but you will need to modify mostly everything in your function to get it working properly *(as there are some missing things and some mistakes in your code)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'increase_shipping_costs', 10, 2);
function increase_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    $rate_multiplier = 1.65; //  65% increase cost
    
    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        
        if ( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id && $rate->cost > 0 ) {
            $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
            $taxes     = array(); // Initializing

            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $rate_multiplier; // Set new rate cost
            
            // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_multiplier; // Set the new tax cost in the array
                    $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                }
            }
            // set array of shipping tax cost
            if( $has_taxes ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    // For a filter hook, always return the main argument
    return $rates; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Answer (score 1):

The filter's callback is not setup properly:

- function parameters are missing
- no value being returned (filters require a return value)

You'll want to use the data provided through the filter (ex: `$package_rates`) rather than `WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones()`.

```php
function increase_shipping_costs( $package_rates, $package ) {
    ...

    return $package_rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'increase_shipping_costs', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Caleb. Would I need to reference shipping zones at all then?

Comment: Hard to know without actually doing the work. Been awhile since I last messed with package rates.